# How to auto populate values for a drop down field in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, dropdown

We have two fields **Fix Versions and Affects Version** in a bug wherein the drop down values are to be auto populated based on the tags created in Azure Repos. For ex: if there are tags v1.001.560, v1.001.561 etc and for any new tags created, the tag version should appear as a drop down value for these fields. Is there a feasible approach to achieve this? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

In short, there is no method to meet your needs now. As a suggestion, you could submit a suggestion ticket to suggest the feature on: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion. That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product group, and makes it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.

DevOps only supports setting to specific values for your custom picklist fields. Please note custom field is used to support tracking data requirements you have that aren't met with the existing set of fields.

Besides, to realize your idea, we should auto populate tag values to the field when opening the work item. However, we also not have such a trigger even though getting the tags with Rest API.